# Sending a message to all channels — Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How do I send a message to every channel in a discord server simultaneously?

I used this code from another post but I receive no response when running the command.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def broadcast(ctx, *, msg):
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for channel in guild.channels:
            try:
                await bot.send_message(channel, msg)
            except Exception:
                continue
            else:
                break
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would make sense to add some `print` statement in the `except` block to see if anything is going wrong.

Comment: Your command has `@client.command()` but you're using `bot.guilds` in the function. Please use only one depending on what you've defined.

Comment: I fiddled with it a little, and ended up getting this error:

 raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: msg is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: That would be because you're not passing any message

Comment: Also, why are you using `else`?

Comment: You should use `ctx.guild.text_channels` instead of `channels` so that way you are only sending messages in text channels instead of categories and voice channels too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've used `client` in some places and `bot` in some other places, more over this code isn't very efficient as it's not required to iterate through the guilds when you're calling it from only one server, that would cause spam in multiple servers. I've also noticed you're using functions from an older version of `discord.py`. Try using this instead:

```py
@client.command()
async def broadcast(ctx, *, msg):
    for channel in ctx.guild.text_channels:
        try:
            await channel.send(msg)
        except:
            continue
```

Comment: @graacelinyoung use `text_channels` instead of `channels`, it'll take lesser time.